# Access to functions through series of classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

Straight forward to get to the problem, is how to access to a function, which is inside a class from another class and from another class. I know how to get access to a function inside a class from another class. But this time is one more class is between them.

**The code:**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        y = x
        print(y)
        self.classb = B()

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print('I am class B')
        self._classC = C()

    def functionb(self):
        print('I am a function in class B')

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        print('I am class C')
    def functionc(self):
        print('I am a function in class C')

Access_to_A = A(1)
```

Calling `def functionc` directly from `class A`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Simply by adding this: `self.classb._classC.functionc()` in your `class A` code...

Comment: Thanks. This is a good and simple answer.